# Node.js TypeError: is not a constructor - Instantiating a class inside a separate class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, babeljs

I'm getting a seemingly strange error for some code I'm trying to implement. This particular bug involves 3 files, structured and written (in a condensed form) as follows.

```
folder
│   SomeFile.js   
│
└───utils
│   │   Paginator.js
│   │   SearchMessage.js
```

---

```js
//----------------Paginator.js----------------------
export default class Paginator {
  constructor(dataArray){
    this.dataArray = dataArray;
  }
//(...)
}


//----------------SearchMessage.js------------------
import {Paginator} from './Paginator.js'
export default class SearchMessage(){
  //(...)
  async sendSearchResults(searchSet){
  //(...)
    const paginator = new Paginator(searchSet);
  }
}


//-----------------SomeFile.js-----------------------
import {SearchMessage} from './utils/SearchMessage.js'
//(...)
const searchMessage = new SearchMessage();
searchMessage.sendSearchResults(searchSet);
```

When calling searchMessage.sendSearchResults(searchSet) in Somefile.js, a TypeError is thrown, `"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: _Paginator.Paginator is not a constructor"`
This implies that paginator is not a proper constructor in that context, which I don't understand. As far as I can tell, the Paginator class is imported properly, and should be able to be instantiated fine.
Additionally, the error persists if paginator is instead instantiated in the SearchMessage constructor.
à la:

```js
//----------------SearchMessage.js------------------
export default class SearchMessage(){
  constructor(searchSet){
    this.paginator = new Paginator(searchSet);
  }
}
```

I'm particularly confused by that fact, as a nearly identical approach works perfectly elsewhere in my project. I'm sure it's something glaringly obvious, but this is truly stumping me so far.
Ex:

```js
//----------------SomeOtherFile.js------------------
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

export default class MongoUtil {
  constructor(collection){
    this.client = new MongoClient(dbURL, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
    this.collectionName = collection;
  }
  async init(){
  await this.client.connect(...)/
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are exporting `SearchMessage` as default, you need to import it via `import SearchMessage from './utils/SearchMessage.js'`. You also need to do the same for when you import `Paginator` in `SearchMessage.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export `Paginator` and `SearchMessage` as default then you need to import them as default as well. Try the following:

```
//----------------SearchMessage.js------------------
import Paginator from './Paginator.js'
export default class SearchMessage(){
  //(...)
  async sendSearchResults(searchSet){
  //(...)
    const paginator = new Paginator(searchSet);
  }
}
```

```
//-----------------SomeFile.js-----------------------
import SearchMessage from './utils/SearchMessage.js'
//(...)
const searchMessage = new SearchMessage();
searchMessage.sendSearchResults(searchSet);
```

Note the changes made to the `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had no idea that was an important differentiation to make, but I definitely won't forget it now lol.